# ¿Como colocar el dato del usuario en el encabezado del NavitationDrawer cuando inicie sesión?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy desarrollando una app en android studio quiero lograr colocar el correo en la parte del header navigationDrawer cada vez que un usuario inicie sesión , he intentando con el siguiente código no se si sea el correcto pero al correr mi aplicación y hacer pruebas me manda un error, y me saca de la aplicación.

**Inicio de sesión del usuario**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Navigation drawer**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**PrincipalActivity.java**

```
public class PrincipalActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

 DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
 ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
 Toolbar toolbar;
 NavigationView navigationView;
 private Usuario user;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);

    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Inicio");

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
    TextView Texv_Email = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.Texv_Email);
    Texv_Email.setText(user.getEmail());
 }
}
```

**Error**

`NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.hdez.logishuman.Usuario.getEmail()' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 0):

El problema que obtienes del LogCat indica que no puedes llamar el método getEmail()   ya que el objeto tiene valor null:

> com.hdez.logishuman.Usuario.getEmail()' on a null object reference

Si revisas el flujo de tu app, la variable `user` nunca es inicializada:

```
public class PrincipalActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

   ...
   ...
   private Usuario user;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
    ...
    ...        
    Texv_Email.setText(user.getEmail());
 }
}
```

Debes asegurar inicializar el objeto user con la propiedad email, seguramente debes tener un setter para esto y agregar la propiedad de email.

```
user = new User();
user.setEmail("Miguel@email.com");
```

Por lo pronto debes al menos validar para evitar el error:

```
 if(user != null){
   Texv_Email.setText(user.getEmail());
 }else{
   Texv_Email.setText("");
 }
```

Comment: Hasta el momento  ya no me sale el error, pero no me muestra el correo del usuario que se esta logueando.

Comment: No te muestra error porque estas validando, el problema es que no estas inicializando el objeto usuario y no le estas guardando la propiedad del email. Debes guardar el email en el objeto cuando asignes el email en la primera pantalla.